# ng-model not working with radio buttons in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-model, ng-submit

I have a simple form with radio buttons that pulls values from a server and loops through them to provide radio buttons:

```
<form ng-submit="createSubCategory(subcategory)">
    <div ng-repeat="sub_category in event_sub_categories" >
        <label class="item item-radio">
                  <input type="radio" ng-model="subcategory" ng-value="'{{sub_category}}'" >
                  <div class="radio-content">
                    <div class="item-content">
                      {{sub_category}}
                    </div>
                    <i class="radio-icon ion-checkmark"></i>
                  </div>
         </label>
    </div>
    <div class="padding">
        <button type="submit" class="button button-block button-positive">Continue</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The form displays perfectly.  However, the radio button that I press doesn't seem to be saving.  Here is the createSubCategory method:

```
$scope.createSubCategory = function(subcategory){
  console.log(subcategory);
}
```

The logs are showing `undefined`.  How do I get the subCategory to be logged after filling out the form?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ng-repeat creates its own scope. Since you're binding your radio buttons to `subcategory`, what is populated is the ng-repeat scope's `subcategory` field, and not the controller scope's `subcategory` field.

Rule of thumb:

- always have a dot in your ng-model
- always create the object containing the fields you're binding to

Also, ng-value expects an angular expression.

So, in your controller, have this:

```
$scope.formModel = {};
```

And in the view:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="formModel.subcategory" ng-value="sub_category" >
```

Comment: Could be the best and most straightforward answer ever on stack overflow.  thank you.